# SelectList in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 page that has to dropdownList contains Sex(male,female) and Role(admin,Operator), in RegisterViewModel I have done like this :

```
  public List<SelectListItem> SelectedItemForSex { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectedItemForRole { get; set; }
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    //public string SelectedValueForRole { get; set; }

public static RegisterViewModel Get()
{
    var model = new RegisterViewModel { SelectedItemForSex = new List<SelectListItem>() };
    model.SelectedItemForSex.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Male", Value = "1" });
    model.SelectedItemForSex.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Femle", Value = "2" });


    model.SelectedItemForRole.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = "Administrator", Value = "1"});
    model.SelectedItemForRole.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text = "Operator", Value = "2"});

    return model;
}
```

and in get action of Register I have this code :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = RegisterViewModel.Get();
            return View(model);
        }
```

and also in razor :

```
 <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(register => register.Sex)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(register => register.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.SelectedItemForSex, "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(register => register.Role)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(register => register.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.SelectedItemForRole, "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
        <div>
```

I know I have Not initialize selectedListItem for Administrator and operator , I wanna to send all of this 4 value via Get() method, How can I do this ??

Comment: your code looks fine from an off hand glance. Have you tried it? Are you getting errors?

Comment: yeah! , object reference not ...! and that is because I have not fill the Roll items in SelectedItemForRole , I just want to send all of the value via a Get method

Comment: Your Model population looks right. Please include your error and the top of your view (the @model ...) to show what model you are binding